# View youtube playlist and watch later offline

Tags: android, web-scraping, youtube, frontend, offlineapps

Sometimes my youtube playlists can get extremely long, and it takes a while to load everything I've saved in them. Is there a way to load an entire Youtube playlist at once and also have the ability to view it offline when I want to? I want this method to also be compatible with Android.

I tried to load the playlists I have manually in the browser I use and save the page as an html, but the page never load properly once finished downloading, and my browser can't understand the file it downloaded either. Android is the operating system I use.

Just to clarify, I am not talking about downloading an entire Youtube playlist. I simply want to view it in the manner of which the Youtube website does, but the entire playlist, without having to load it all manually and offline. If not in the same way the Youtube webpage does, at least in a way where I can view the thumbnails and the titles in an easy to read order. It also must be available for Android.